# Unzip gz archives with zip extension

Tags: zip, gzip

I have a number of gzip archives; however they have a zip extension not gz:
***.zip

When I try to unzip them with `unzip`, I get `not a zip archive` error, and with gunzip I get `unknown suffix: zip`

What is going on here really?

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't rename the files to have a `.gz` extension?

Answer (score 12):

By default, `gzip` will only decompress files with extensions from a limited list—rather than examining the file `magic` to determine if it is a gzip'd file.  From a comment in `gzip.c`:`get_suffix()`:

```
/* ========================================================================                 
 * Return a pointer to the 'z' suffix of a file name, or NULL. For all                      
 * systems, ".gz", ".z", ".Z", ".taz", ".tgz", "-gz", "-z" and "_z" are                     
 * accepted suffixes, in addition to the value of the --suffix option.
```

To use input files which are in fact gzip'd but are not named following `gzip`'s expected conventions, provide the suffix explicitly as per the [`gzip` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip):

> **-S .suf --suffix .suf**
>
> ... When decompressing, add .suf to the beginning of the list of suffixes to try, when deriving an output file name from an input file name.

```
$ gunzip -S .zip foo.zip
```

or use redirection to prevent `gzip` from seeing the filename:

```
$ gunzip < foo.zip > foo.txt
```

Comment: +1 for a cause - but why not `cat file.zip | gunzip > file.ext` for the quick lazy way of doing it?  And if `cat` will interrupt due to the "special" characters that would show in a binary, would `dd` work in its place - `dd if=filezame.zip | gunzip > filename.ext`